# Maximizing GLMM Likelihood in R

Tags: r, mixed-models

Is there an R function/package similar to SAS PROC NLMIXED? I want to specify a likelihood function (which includes random effects, assumed MVN) and maximize this approximated likelihood via a Gaussian Quadrature or AGQ approach.

My end goal is random effects beta regression model (with a dispersion sub-model). Currently I don't think this functionality exists in the package `betareg` or via `family` argument of `glmer` `lme4`?

Below is my SAS PROC NLMIXED code:

```
proc nlmixed data=ttt method=gauss tech=trureg qpoints=5 ;
parms b0=0 b1=0 b00=1 b11=0 s2u=1 ;
bounds s2u>=0 ;
eta_mean = b0 + b1*x + u ;
eta_prec = b00 + b11*x ; 
mu = exp(eta_mean)/(1 + exp(eta_mean));
phi = exp(eta_prec) ;
w = mu*phi;
t = phi - mu*phi;
ll = lgamma(w+t) - lgamma(w) - lgamma(t) + ((w-1)*log(y)) + ((t-1)*log(1 - y));
model y ~ general(ll);
random u ~ normal(0, s2u) subject=clust ;
run;
```

How would one deal with the random effects (quadrature) using R optimizers like `nlminb` or `optim`? Or is there some other combination of R functions better suited for maximizing rather general GLMM likelihoods in R?

Comment: the `glmmADMB` package can do a random-effects beta regression ...